# Return from a BackgroundWorker from within a method called by it

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` that calls a method that calls a method... and somewhere along the line I check for `CancellationPending` and want to exit the `BackgroundWorker`.

Is there a way to do that directly from that deeply nested method or does it have to return to its caller, which in turn will return to its caller...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about the fact that you're using a `BackgroundWorker` - think about this in the same terms as you would just dealing with deeply nested method calls.

In other words, no, there's no (non-horrible) way I can think of to do that directly.

The cleanest way I can think of is to simply check for `CancellationPending` immediately after you return from each nested method, at every level (and if `true`, return).

Throwing a specific exception and catching same specific exception type at the top level would get you out quickly but isn't exactly best practice (which is, don't use exceptions anything non-exceptional, like normal flow control).

Answer (score 3):

> a BackgroundWorker that calls a method that calls a method ...
>
> Is there a way to do that [cancel] directly from that deeply nested method

You could throw an exception. But that is borderline with the general advice to only use exceptions for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you shouldn't.

Aside from throwing exceptions as mentioned in other answers, the evil whose name no one dares speak is [Thread.Abort()](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=c#%20thread.abort&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=EPqHUIGhEofg2AXk3IHgAw&usg=AFQjCNHCJuI9Cj5CpplEqoe9IhKJpXWBnA).  If you call this from a function executing on the BackgroundWorker thread, the whole thread will quit.  The evils of Thread.Abort() have been discussed at great length [elsewhere on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244319/is-thread-abort-corruption-localized).

That being said, the correct thing to do is to structure your code so that when a deeply-nested function decides that the thread should exit, this intention is propogated back up the stack to the main thread method, which can then exit cleanly

Comment: The background thread itself is what wants to leave, not the caller, so there would be no use or place for thread.abort.  As others have said, you could explicitly throw an exception.  It would actually be *much* less bad that thread.Abort.  You could ensure that the exception is thrown in such a way that you won't cause deadlocks, will actually exit the thread, won't leave undisposed resources, etc.  It would still be a bit of a bad practice, but one that's quite a lot more livable.

Comment: I meant that the deeply-nested function could call Thread.Abort() on the current thread.  I believe this is relevant to the questioner's problem unless I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: Calling thread.abort just throws an exception in that thread, so calling abort on yourself wouldn't really be different than just throwing an exception, but throwing an explicit exception would be preferable in that the exception message would be more appropriate.  Note that most of the problems of `Thread.Abort` are a direct result of it being called from another thread, so you don't know where the exception will be thrown from.  It could be thrown from the middle of a blocking IO call, in a finally block or catch block, it could be caught and swallowed by the thread, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to it, I prefer this implementation, although it restricts arguments a little bit but you can change that. The main point is that you are passing the reference to the `BackgroudWorker` as a parameter:

```
bkgw = new BackgroundWorker();
bkgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bkgw_DoWork);
bkgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;



void bkgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        BackgroundWorker b = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        if (b.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        if (!Method1(b))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
        if (b.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

}

bool Method1(BackgroundWorker caller)
{
    //some code
    if (caller.CancellationPending)
        return false;
    if (!Method2(caller))
        return false;
    //some code
    return true;
}
bool Method2(BackgroundWorker caller)
{
    //some code
    if (caller.CancellationPending)
        return false;
    //some code
    return true;
}
```